# Unity3D vibrating and choppy scroll (with live demo + WebGL compared)

Tags: unity-game-engine, xna, game-engine, direct3d, unity-webgl

Something must wrong here either with me or my monitor or GPU. Others also suffer from this phenomena see the links.

Now I would like to emphasize this problem is exist, being optimist I think there is some solution. Maybe it is only noticeable in special circumstances, and definitely not a performance (or GC) problem. If it would noticeable in all circumstances Unity3D would be useless... 
My goal to use this wider forum to specify this problem is my hope the wider community may have wider scope to search the root of the problem. I think it is not algorithm or Time class usage related. Maybe the Time.deltaTime itself has bugs or mislead in some circumstances.

Just a feedback if anyone can reproduce the vibrating effect or not may have diagnostic value. (it seems to be oscillating in horizontal, the left and right edges are very blurry.)

Marrt created a web demo for Unity to demonstrate the effect:
http://marrt.elementfx.com/SmoothMovementTest.html

Whatever I do this demo is *so* vibrating + choppy. NOTE: All my self created simple scroll projects running in editor or standalone desktop are also exhibits the *same*, so it is not about 'how to use Time.deltaTime'

I thought the problem is in my hardware until today I saw this WebGL demo (use Chrome):

http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html

It is so smooth (any fish movement, also the rotating also the light fades) I mean *smoooth*. Why I can not produce (no one produce) this with Unity (at least in my machine)?

If anyone interested there is an exact proble description here, but no all answers solve the problem.

The problem in details:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/275016/updatefixedupdate-motion-stutter-not-another-novic.html

I tried all the things including the programming variations + quality setting (VSync etc)
My very simple self created projects are running 1000 - 2000 fps and still vibrating + choppy.

I spent 2 days to get the rid of this poor visual experience. Did all the programming thing what mentioned in the linked threads + tried to configure my video card (btw Radeon 6770 with 1Gigs)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not clear what your problem is.  Firstly, you say that you're sure it's not a programming problem - which suggests it's offtopic for StackOverflow.  Also, you link to a demo project, but I see no choppiness and I don't know what you mean by "vibrating effect."  Can you be clearer about what your problem is please?

Comment: Some code for testing would be nice. The link to SmoothMovementTest.unitypackage supplied in the forum crashes when running on Unity 3.5.6

Comment: Have read your Unity Answers thread too (you should copy the relevant information to here so that people don't have to hunt elsewhere). The GC questions are unfounded; that won't be your immediate problem in such a small demo, and Vector3 won't typically come under GC anyway (one of the answers confirms that).

Comment: Dan, thx for you comments. 1) Yes as I wrote it is not GC. 2) Vibrating: it seems to be oscillating in horizontal, the left and right edges are very blurry. 3) It is definitely _development_ tool related, as only Unity3D exhibits it on my machine so it is not offtopic I hope.

Comment: Kay, for me the link does not crash, but I copy here too:
http://forum.unity3d.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=41949&d=1355632275
Also: Do you see the very poor visual experience in the live web demo?

Comment: I see it clearly in Firefox having 10-15 other tabs open). In Safari with one tab (this URL only) it's visible but not that much. It was exactly that link and I tried it again - Unity crash when I try to load the scene

Comment: Kay: Maybe it was exported with Unity3D 4? Are you using 3.x?

Comment: It was definitely exported with 4.0.0f7. It could crash if one trying to import into Unity 3.5.x